# How does socket recv function detects end of message

Tags: sockets

Look at this small basic python programs:

```
import socket

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind(("", 10000))

tcpsock.listen(10)
(sock, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()

s = sock.recv(1024)
print(s)
```

Second program:

```
import socket
import time

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 10000))
time.sleep(1)
sock.sendall(b'hello world')
```

The first program is a socket server. It recv a message through the socket and display it on the console. The second program is a client which connects to the server and sends it a message.

As you can see, the server reads a 1024 bytes max length message. My client send a few bytes.
My question is: How does the server knows the message ends after the 'd' char ?

I am working with sockets since years and i have always implemented a delimiter mechanism in order to know when the message stops.
But it seems to work automaticly. My question is: How ?
I know TCP car fragment messages. So what's happen if the paquet is trucated in the middle of my message ? Is it managed by OS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

> How does the server knows the message ends after the 'd' char ?

It does not. There is not even a concept of a message in TCP. `recv` simply returns what is there: it blocks if no data are available and returns what can be read **up to** the given size if data are available. "Data available" means that there are data in the sockets receive buffer, which are put by the OS kernel there. In other words: `recv` will not block until the requested number of bytes can be returned but it will already return when at least a single byte is in the sockets receive buffer.

For example if the client would do two `send` or `sendall` shortly after each other a single `recv` might return both "messages" together. This can be easily triggered by deferring the `recv` (add some sleep before it) so that both "messages" are guaranteed to be arrived at the client.

Comment: Thanks but i do not understand how recv takes decision to break after 11 chars in my case. There could be a 12th or 13th chars ? Is there a timeout ? Thanks

Comment: Recv just returns as much already-received data as it can fit into your buffer.  Eg If there were 11 bytes in the tcp stack’s incoming-data-buffer for your socket, and your buffer is at least 11 bytes long, then it returns 11 bytes.  The number of bytes present in the tcp stack’s incoming-data-buffer will depend on how many tcp packets were received before you called recv(), and how much data each of them contained — and that will depend on the performance characteristics of the network and the (rather elaborate) algorithm tcp uses to maximize throughput in response to network behavior.